# VC2010 beginner question: syntax "^"

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

A causal VC++ user here.

I have started a 'Windows Forms Application' project in VC 2010 express. When I double clicked on a dummy button on a form, it takes me to an editor windows and jumps right into this piece of code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            // do excel
         }
};
```

Question:

1) I wonder what does the "^" here means?

2) Why does this piece of code live in a header file (.h)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is C++/CLI. This allow accessing .NET (CLI) object from C++.

1. The `^` means this is a object handle (the usual way of passing data in C#). See the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) for some brief idea.
2. Why in a `.h` file? In C/C++, you can put code in header file.  Just putting prototype is just a matter of style. There are no syntax enforcement of this.